# object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python, django

I am working on CS50 django project, yet i keep receiving the error of " object has no attribute 'cleaned_data". I have read all the related question but still cant figure out my problem

here is my script of view.py

```
class NewTitleForm(forms.Form):
newtitle = forms.CharField(label="title ")


class NewContentForm(forms.Form):
    newcontent = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":5, "cols":5}))

def newpage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        titleinput = NewTitleForm(request.POST)
        contentinput = NewContentForm(request.POST)
        if titleinput.is_valid():
            newtitle = titleinput.cleaned_data["newtitle"]
            newcontent = contentinput.cleaned_data["newcontent"]
            util.save_entry(newtitle,newcontent)
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html", {
                "NewTitleForm": NewTitleForm(),
                "NewContentForm": NewContentForm()
            })
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html",{
        "NewTitleForm": NewTitleForm(),
        "NewContentForm": NewContentForm()
    })
```

And the error code is

```
AttributeError: 'NewContentForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

I have no idea what's going on

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: File "C:\wiki\encyclopedia\views.py", line 36, in newpage
    newcontent = contentinput.cleaned_data["newcontent"]
AttributeError: 'NewContentForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `contentinput.is_valid()` too.

like this:

```
def newpage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        titleinput = NewTitleForm(request.POST)
        contentinput = NewContentForm(request.POST)
        if titleinput.is_valid() and contentinput.is_valid():
            newtitle = titleinput.cleaned_data["newtitle"]
            newcontent = contentinput.cleaned_data["newcontent"]
            util.save_entry(newtitle,newcontent)
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html", {
                "NewTitleForm": NewTitleForm(),
                "NewContentForm": NewContentForm()
            })
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/newpage.html",{
        "NewTitleForm": NewTitleForm(),
        "NewContentForm": NewContentForm()
    })
```

`cleaned_data` won't exist until you call the form method `is_valid`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NewContentForm` class inherits from a `forms.Form` class. So, when you try to access the `cleaned_data` attribute, it's looking for a class attribute either on `NewContentForm` or inherited from `forms.Form`. If that attribute doesn't exist on either class (and it doesn't exist on your current `NewContentForm`) then it will result in that Attribute Error. So you either need to confirm that `cleaned_data` is an attribute that exists on `forms.Form` or add it to the `NewContentForm` class.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html